# How to apply UITapGestureRecognizer on a specific label having some tag in objective c

Tags: tags, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 4 labels in a loop and i want to apply `UITapGestureRecognizer` on each label individually to perform some action how can i got this stuff if i want to apply gestures only on label with tag 2 any help please.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
  label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    label.tag = LABEL_TAG+i;

    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    label.text = @"someText";
    [label sizeToFit];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
    [self viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG+2 addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You only need to add UITapGestureRecognizer on each label.

for(UIlabel *label in cell.contentViews.subviews) {
    if(label.tag == 1) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    } }
```

Comment: but i,m not using any tabelView

Comment: You can simply add a invisible  button on the label. I hope this trick will help you.

Comment: what is cell in this case?

Comment: Cell of a UItableview .

Comment: You can have  four labels in a UITableviewCell and can implement this .

Comment: But i not need tableview

Comment: we can get with tapGestures too but i not understanding how can  i apply conditions  with tags

Comment: Then Simply take four labels in a Array. and at the index 2 of Array you can add your tap gesture.  and on others you simply skip the loop.You should run loop from 1 to 4.

Comment: can you explain with any sample please?